# Running tensorflow-gpu on vm-linux with ext. GPU and host macOS

Tags: macos, tensorflow, virtual-machine

I have a linux machine and a mac. Linux is used mostly for running ml stuff with CUDA, Mac I use for entertainment and media editing..

Recently I had this crazy idea..

Running tensorflow-GPU with egpu+vm ubuntu. Has anyone tried this?
Is this even possible?

Comment: TensorFlow documention says on osx you won't have gpu

Comment: what i meant to say was: run tensorflow-gpu on linux. But this linux is not a native OS. It will be run through virtual machine. Now with dgpu, this would not work because of the PCIE pass-through issue with the virtual machine. But with egpu... I was hoping things will be different..